# How do I continue installing or downloading a module that failed to download using pip install?

Tags: tensorflow, pip

Here I am trying to pip install tensorflow and our internet connection was so bad that it failed several time. And you know when running another pip installation on the same module it will start from the beginning.

So, I was wondering if there is a way to continue from where the download was interrupted.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can resume a failed or interrupted pip installation by using the --no-cache-dir option along with --no-binary :all:.

This will prevent pip from using cached downloads, which might have been corrupted due to the interrupted download.

Instead, it will try to download the package again from the beginning but will continue the download where it left off.

`pip install --no-cache-dir --no-binary :all: tensorflow`

In this above command tells pip to not use the cache directory and not to use any pre-built binary packages. It will then attempt to download the package again from the beginning but will resume the download.

Keep in mind that the interruption must have occurred during the download phase. if the installation process itself was interrupted, this method might not work.